# Wrap inherited method in aliases

Tags: ruby, inheritance, methods

I want to provide a consistent interface by inheriting from a base class. But certain methods on that base class I would like to wrap with additional functionality.

Let's say every subclass will have an eat method:

```
class ClassyAnimal

  def self.inherited(base)
    base.class_eval do
      alias :eat_without_napkin :eat
      alias :eat :eat_with_napkin 
    end
  end

  def eat_with_napkin
    begin
      eat_without_napkin
    rescue FoodOutOfMouthError
      puts 'phew!'
    end
  end

  def eat
    raise 'Please implement the #eat method.'
  end
end

class ClassyWalrus < ClassyAnimal

  def eat
    puts 'Eating Cronuts.'
    raise FoodOutOfMouthError.new('Damn these tusks!')
    puts 'Finishing my meal.'
  end
end

class FoodOutOfMouthError < StandardError; end
```

Now I would hope that `ClassyWalrus.new.eat` would output the following:

```
Eating Cronuts.
phew!
```

Unfortunately, we get the following:

```
Eating Cronuts.
FoodOutOfMouthError: Damn these tusks!
```

At the time of inheritance, and therefore at time of `alias`, #eat is defined as the one inside of ClassyAnimal instead of the one inside of ClassyWalrus. The aliased #eat then gets overridden by the subclass, and the wrapping is lost.

What can be done?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following additions to the code.

in class `ClassyAnimal`:

```
  def eat_with_napkin
    begin
      yield
    rescue FoodOutOfMouthError
      puts 'phew!'
    end
  end
```

in class `ClassyWalrus`:

```
  def eat
    puts 'Eating Cronuts.'
    superclass.eat do
      raise FoodOutOfMouthError.new('Damn these tusks!')
    end
    puts 'Finishing my meal.'
  end
```

Comment: That would work, but I'd like to avoid requiring each implementation from explicitly calling super or manually wrapping the call. #eat should be the things that need to be done, which I'd like to wrap with additional functionality (logging, error handling, instrumentation.) They shouldn't be able to accidentally forget to call the method.

Comment: @Chris, I see your point, but one could just as well forget to raise the exception in the subclass `eat` method.  Isn't that in effect a way of calling a method in the base class?  If you do call methods in the base class, is there any point in having the `inherited` hook and aliases?

Comment: because `self.inherited(base)` is called just on class inheritance at `ClassyWalrus < ClassyAnimal` you can't alias fucntions before definition of them. I'll think

Comment: @CarySwoveland unfortunately the exceptions are not always expected (explicitly raised) and there is far more than a `begin/rescue` clause to be wrapped :( The other option is to have the child implement #eat but be called as `ClassyWalrus.eat`.

Comment: @majioa you're right about that. The only way I could get it to work with alias was to put that all the way at the bottom of the `ClassyWalrus` definition. It actually aliases ClassyAnimal#eat and then overrides it in the subclass

Comment: @Chris what? I didn't understand. What do you mean about putting the alias all the way at the bottom? Does it matter where you write them in the base class?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility I thought of, which I believe is how ActionMailer does this, is to define the method on the child as an instance variable, but invoke it on the class itself.

This isn't exactly what I'm looking for, so I won't accept this answer, but just to document it.

```
class ClassyAnimal
  def self.eat
    if instance_methods.include? :eat
      begin
        self.new.eat
      rescue FoodOutOfMouthError
        puts 'phew!'
      end
    end
  end
end

class ClassyWalrus < ClassyAnimal

  def eat
    puts 'Eating Cronuts.'
    raise FoodOutOfMouthError.new('Damn these tusks!')
    puts 'Finishing my meal.'
  end
end

class FoodOutOfMouthError < StandardError; end
```

Which would be called as:

```
ClassyWalrus.eat
# outputs => Eating Cronuts.
# outputs => phew!
```